# Firefox showing records size as 2MB ,

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Am simply executing query ,

The record count just 2980 , but it allocate around 2MB ,

I dont How its 2mb,

just rendering records without css ,

how to track , For what reason it showing as  2MB ,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

2980 records that contain some data and are wrapped in a bunch of HTML may well amount to about 2MB of data. Save the site to disk or `curl` it into a file from the command line and check yourself, if you don't believe Firefox.

IMO, 2980 records on a single page sounds like quite some madness, not only because of the resulting file size. You should paginate the data.

Comment: how to test with curl command line, is there any tutorial for this

Comment: @Bhar `curl http://example.com/site > somefile` That's assuming you're running on some UNIX derivative and/or have `curl` installed. Probably won't work on Windows that easily. All it does is give you the raw site, you can do the same by saving the site in your browser or use "View Source".